# Tensorflow: weight decay vs logits normalization

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am working on a CNN of similar architecture as in [cifar10](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10) example. My CNN consists of two convolutional layers, each followed by a max-pooling layer, and three fully connected layers. All layers except final one use [`relu`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#relu) activation function. Final layer yields logits of order `10^5`, so running softmax function results in one-hot encoding. I tried to solve this problems in two different ways.

Firstly, I simply rescaled logits to `[-1, 1]`, i.e. normalized them. This seems to solve the problem, training goes fine and CNN produces reasonable result. But I am not sure if it is the right way to go, it feels like normalizing logits is a workaround that does not solve the initial problem. 
[image]

Secondly, I applied weight decay. Without logits normalization cross-entropy starts from large values but it goes down steadily as total weight loss does. However accuracy produces a weird pattern. Moreover, network trained with weight decay produces much worse results than the one with logits normalization.
[image]

Weight decay is added as follows:

```
def weight_decay(var, wd):
    weight_decay = tf.mul(tf.nn.l2_loss(var), wd, name='weight_loss')
    tf.add_to_collection('weight_losses', weight_decay)
```

Accuracy

```
predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
one_hot_pred = tf.argmax(predictions, 1)
correct_pred = tf.equal(one_hot_pred, tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy_batch = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

So how should one address the problem of large magnitude logits? What is the best practice? What can be a reason why applying weight decay produces worse result?

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, `tf.nn.l2_loss(var)` is not normalized, in other words, maybe your `wd` is too big, or somehow not suitable.